# Vb.net : Interop exception when showAllData() on Excel sheet?

Tags: vb.net, interop, excel, vba

I have some filters applied on my input excel sheets, so I decided to remove them using `showAllData()` method in vb.net.

MSDN Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178108(v=office.12).aspx

But it is giving a very strange exception on that line : `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

My code :

```
sh = myWorkBook.Sheets(2)
' sh is my sheet
sh.Visible = True
sh.Activate()
sh.Select()
sh.ShowAllData()     ' Exception raised on this line
```

What am I doing wrong ?

What is this exception, I have seen this a lot lately. But its never clear what went wrong ?

Comment: Feel free to ask for extra info, If I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it fixed :

The sheets that I was using for input didn't had filtered data when tested.

So, here goes the code change :

```
sh = myWorkBook.Sheets(2)
' sh is my sheet
sh.Visible = True
sh.Activate()
sh.Select()
If sh.FilterMode = True Then
    sh.ShowAllData()
End If
```

The extra `if`, solved the issue.

But still the raised exception was not at all helpful. Explain the exception if someone can.

Answer (score 0):

> > > But still the raised exception was not at all helpful. Explain the exception if someone can.

ShowAllData() gives an error if the data is not filtered and hence you have to check for it as you rightly did :)

Here is another way to do it

```
        On Error Resume Next
        xlsheet.ShowAllData()
        On Error GoTo 0
```

And to remove the AutoFilter you can use this code

```
        If xlsheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then xlsheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```